# Coq can't see that two types are the same

Tags: types, functional-programming, coq

I am trying to define the rev function on a vector, the size of it is embedded in it and I can't figure out how to define the rev function on it.

Here is my type definition:

```coq
Inductive vect {X : Type} : nat -> Type -> Type
  := Nil  : vect 0 X
   | Cons : forall n, X -> vect n X -> vect (S n) X
.
```

---

I have defined some useful functions on it:

```ocaml
Fixpoint app {X : Type} {n m : nat} (v1 : vect n X) (v2 : vect m X)
: vect (n + m) X :=
  match v1 with
    | Nil => v2
    | Cons _ x xs => Cons _ x (app xs v2)
  end.

Fixpoint fold_left {X Y : Type} {n : nat} (f : Y -> X -> Y) (acc : Y) (v : vect n X)
: Y :=
  match v with
    | Nil => acc
    | Cons _ x xs => fold_left f (f acc x) xs
  end.
```

---

And now, I want to define rev. My first tentative was through fold_left but it turned out to be a total failure.

```ocaml
Fixpoint rev {X : Type} {n : nat} (v : @vect X n X) : @vect X n X :=
  fold_left (fun {X : Type} {k : nat} (acc : vect k X) (x : X) => x ::: acc) {{ }} v.
```

I don't understand the error `Error: The type of this term is a product while it is expected to be a sort.`.

---

My second tentative is almost good but Coq can't see that "S n = (n + 1)" natively and I don't know how to tell Coq so.

```ocaml
Fixpoint rev {X : Type} {n : nat} (v : @vect X n X) : @vect X n X :=
  match v in (vect n X) return (vect n X) with
    | Nil => Nil
    | Cons _ x xs => app (rev xs) {{ x }}
  end.
```

The error being `The term "app (rev X n0 xs) {{x}}" has type "vect (n0 + 1) X" while it is expected to have type "vect (S n0) X"`

If you have any other remarks on the coq code do not hesitate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Fixpoint rev {X : Type} {n : nat} (v : @vect X n X) : @vect X n X :=
>   fold_left (fun {X : Type} {k : nat} (acc : vect k X) (x : X) => Cons x acc) Nil v.
> ```

The first explicit argument to `fold_left` must have a type of the form `?1 -> ?2 -> ?1`, i.e. a function of two arguments whose return type is the same as the first argument. [Dependent] “product” is Coq terminology for a function. You're passing a term of the form `fun (X:Type) b c d => …`, so `?1` is `Type`, and the term `fun c d => …` (which obviously has a product type) must have the type `?` given the context, so it must have the type `Type`, i.e. it must be a sort.

If you try to fix this, you'll realize that your `fold_left` function doesn't work here: you need to vary the length of the vector during the iteration, but the iterator argument to `fold_left` has a type that's constant during the iteration. With the `fold_left` function that you have, if you start from the accumulator `Nil`, which is a vector of length 0, you'll end up with a result of the same type, again a vector of length 0.

I haven't thought about how to define a more general iterator that would let you define `rev`, but I'm sure it's possible.

---

As to your second attempt, the problem with `vect (n0 + 1) X` and `vect (S n0) X` is that they are not the same type, because `n0 + 1` is not convertible to `S n0`. The terms `n0 + 1` are equal but not convertible, and terms used as types are only interchangeable if they're convertible.

If two types are equal, you can write a function that “casts” a term of one type into a term of the other type. In fact, the general function to do that is `eq_rect`, the destructor for the equality type family. You may find it to define a specialized function to cast a vector to a vector of provably-but-not-necessarily-convertibly equal length.

```
Definition vect_eq_nat {X : Type} {m n : nat} (H : m = n) v :=
  eq_rect _ (fun k => @vect X k X) v _ H.
```

If the usage of `eq_rect` doesn't immediately stand out, you can define such functions through tactics. Just be sure that you're defining a function that not only has the right type but has the desired result, and make the definition transparent.

```
Definition vect_eq_nat {X : Type} {m n : nat} : m = n -> @vect X m X -> @vect X n X.
intros.
rewrite <- H.
exact X0.
Defined.
Print vect_eq_nat.
```

You can also use the `Program` vernacular to mix proofs and terms.

```
Program Definition vect_plus_comm {X : Type} {n : nat} (v : @vect X (n+1) X) : @vect X (S n) X :=
  vect_eq_nat _ v.
Require Import Arith.
Require Import Omega.
Solve Obligation 0 using (intros; omega).
```

Now you can use this auxiliary definition to define `rev`.

```
Fixpoint rev {X : Type} {n : nat} (v : @vect X n X) : @vect X n X :=
  match v in (vect n X) return (vect n X) with
    | Nil => Nil
    | Cons _ x xs => vect_plus_comm (app (rev xs) (Cons _ x Nil))
  end.
```

You can use `Program Fixpoint` to define `rev` directly, once you've put that casting step in place. The one proof obligation is the equality between `S n0` and `n0 + 1`.

```
Program Fixpoint rev' {X : Type} {n : nat} (v : @vect X n X) : @vect X n X :=
  match v in (vect n X) return (vect n X) with
    | Nil => Nil
    | Cons _ x xs => vect_eq_nat _ (app (rev' xs) (Cons _ x Nil))
  end.
Solve Obligation 0 using (intros; omega).
```

Comment: A type for `fold_left` that works is `forall (X : Type) (Y : nat -> Type) (n k : nat), (forall m : nat, Y m -> X -> Y (S m)) -> Y k -> vect X n -> Y (n + k)`.